# sharepoint dynamically add list item to a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like use the values from a list of projects to populate multiple different pages with the contents of the list. For example, in the list I would have Project A and Project B, etc. I want to make a site dedicated to Project A and have the content that is in the project list (i.e. due dates, employees working on project, etc) fill in the template for Site "Project A" using a Script Editor web part. I am told that this can be done dynamically with JQuery such that if I change a project on the list later, then the site for that specific project will reflect the changes in the list.

So as an example, lets say the list looks like this:

Project list
Project     Employee     Location
Project A   Employee A   123 A St
Project B   Employee B   234 B St
Project C   Employee C   345 C St

Then I would want the site to have a script editor that looks like this:

Project A (title)

Employee A

Location A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. I would prefer that you call the lists content in the ScriptEditor WebPart by the name of the project. That means you take the projectname from List I -> Project A, create a Page or Site for this Projekt with the same Title -> Project A and via the Script Editor you will query the list for the projects details by the title (projectname). The only thing is, that the projects need to have unique names.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

And instead of using an alert as shown in this example to view the listitems data, you could also assign the value of the listitem to a div container via

```
$("myDIV_ID").update("My text");
```

From [How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: awesome thank you! I'm assuming under the retrieveListItems method, that the "siteUrl" variable should be filled in with the actual URL? Also, does this code need to be in <script> tags or just standalone in the script editor?

Comment: it can be inside scrpt tags or in an script editor webpart. its up to you. please dont forget to mark as answer if it helped.